# text does not word wrap inside a table

Tags: css

I want the text inside my table to word-wrap. The constraint is that I can't change the HTML since it's generated by the server.

I created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y5zbe/)

In case it's not working:

```
<div style="width: 25%">
    <table class="af_selectManyCheckbox" id="pt1:r1:1:smc1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="af_selectManyCheckbox_label" valign="top"/>
                <td valign="top" class="AFContentCell" nowrap="">
                    <div class="af_selectManyCheckbox_content">
                        <div>
                            <span class="af_selectManyCheckbox_content-input">
                                <input class="af_selectManyCheckbox_native-input" type="checkbox" value="0"/>
                            </span>
                            <label class="af_selectManyCheckbox_item-text">It allows a component to partially refresh another component whose partialSubmit property is set to true.</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go.

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/y5zbe/1/)**

**The CSS Code:**

```
.col-md-3 label {
    white-space: normal;
}
```

Hope this helps.